# Where can I find a good Drupal chat-room here on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, chat

Where can I find a good Drupal chat-room here on Stack Overflow?

It should only concern Drupal 7 and Drupal 8.

Comment: On a side note, I doubt such a room would be very active if similar rooms for similar software are any indication.

Comment: There's an entire site for drupal users in [drupal.se]

Answer (score 12):

You can find all chatrooms [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms?tab=all&sort=active).

There doesn't seem to be any room for Drupal yet. Once you have [100 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) you can create such a chatroom yourself. Whether or not it will become good is hard to predict now. Its worth noting that in order to succeed, a chatroom needs both consistent activity and a number of regular users.

If a Drupal only chatroom is not feasible you might check one of the tool stack rooms. Drupal uses PHP, Javascript and HTML/CSS. Those are all active rooms, with a bit care they might tolerate a Drupal dev.

But first you need to reach [20 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat) so you can talk in chat.

On the Stack Exchange chat server [Drupal Answers](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=drupal.stackexchange.com) has several rooms. I'm not able to judge their quality. You might want to lurk a bit there.