# Is Chat part of Stack Overflow or the software that powers the SE network?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, vote-to-close, chat

This [Meta Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332854/where-can-i-find-a-good-drupal-chat-room-here-on-stack-overflow) was happily [closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/332854/timeline) (now reopened) with the reason:

> "This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center."

The question ask about the existence of a toolstack-specific chatroom. I answered the question while I saw the close votes coming in. I was not surprised about the closing (too broad, unclear could have worked as well), but that reason is not correct, IMHO.

I checked with one of the close voters, and their reaction was:

> Are chat rooms core features of the SO site actually?
>   Well, as mentioned I didn't consider chat as a core feature of the SE (SO) engine.

Do these statements have merit? Are we supposed to close questions about the software that make up chat rooms? Are those questions off-topic on MSO?

Comment: _"happily closed"_ Is a big wording. Nothing made me happy about that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ *happily* refers to the post, not to users. You should know that drill by now ...

Comment: Well, that's why I put an upvote over here.

Comment: I would say "chat" is a core feature, though individual chat rooms may not be "supported" by SE, per se. However I do not think that a question about chat or chat rooms should be off topic for that reason because technically it is about something that resides on stack overflow.

Comment: The question you link shouldn't have been closed. It has a very clear and specific answer (the one you gave) meaning it was not unclear or broad, and it most definitely is related to SO functionality. There does seem to be a problem with questions being falsely closed too often on Meta. Perhaps it's caused by the higher ratio of high rep users viewing a post.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This seems like a rather silly question. One can debate all day long about whether chat is a "core" feature of Stack Overflow (and, similarly, Stack Exchange). I'm inclined to say no, in the sense that one is not (and should not be) required to participate in chat in order to be a productive and informed member of Stack Overflow. As many people know, I am not a big fan of chat, and prefer to abstain from this feature.

But I don't deny that it *exists*, and that is really the core point. Because it exists, and because it is part of Stack Overflow (hosted on the same domain, run by the same people, integrated with the web site, has the same moderators, uses the same reputation system, etc. etc.), the Stack Overflow Meta site is the place where you can ask questions about, get support for, and post feature requests for chat.

If you don't use chat, then such Meta questions will be uninteresting or irrelevant for you. That's fine; filter them out based on the presence of the [chat](/questions/tagged/chat) tag. But don't turn away people from asking them based on some silly semantics about whether or not chat is a "core" feature. It is a *supported* feature, and it belongs here unless and until there is a http://meta.chat.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I'm awaiting your FR to start http://meta.chat.stackoverflow.com/. And just allow me one silly question ... ;)

Comment: Is meta.chat.stackoverflow.com going to be a Q&A, or a chat? :-)

Comment: @Palec meta.chat.stackoverflow.com would be a Q&A and there would be a separate chat.meta.chat.stackoverflow.com for chat about that.

Comment: @BhargavRao and of course, you’d need meta.chat.meta.chat.stackoverflow.com for discussion about the chat about the discussion about the chat about Stack Overflow. (repeat until the subdomain limit is reached).

Comment: @JF where do we go to ask a question about how to ask a question about the discussion about the chat about the discussion about the chat about Stack Overflow?

Comment: @RobertColumbia I’ve heard that [this site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/error) accepts all kinds of questions.

Answer (score -11):

You're conveniently ignoring half of the quoted sentence:

> This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network

Yes, *of course* chat is part of this software.

> within the scope defined in the help center.

You fell over here. Asking people to perform a search of chatrooms for you is not a good meta question.

Unfortunately, the link to the Meta Help Centre has somehow become a link to the main Help Centre, so that's pretty useless.